# Is this an F# compiler bug? #3

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, struct, warnings

Signature file `Foo.fsi`:

```
namespace FooBarSoftware
open System.Collections.Generic

[<Struct>]
type Foo<'T> =
     new: unit -> 'T Foo
     new: 'T   -> 'T Foo

     // doesn't exists in implementation!
     member public GetEnumerator: unit -> IEnumerator<'T>
     interface IEnumerable<'T>
```

Implementation file `Foo.fs`:

```
namespace FooBarSoftware
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

[<Struct>]
type Foo<'T> =
     val offset: int
     new (x:'T) = { offset = 1 }

     interface IEnumerable<'T> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = null :> IEnumerator<'T>
        member this.GetEnumerator() = null :> IEnumerator
```

This compiles fine, but with warning `FS0314`:

> The type definitions in the signature and implementation are not compatible because the field offset was present in the implementation but not in the signature. Struct types must now reveal their fields in the signature for the type, though the fields may still be labelled 'private' or 'internal'.

When I run the code like that, I've got `MethodMissingException`:

```
let foo = FooBarSoftware.Foo<int>() // <==

// System.MethodMissingException:
// Method not found: 'Void FooBarSoftware.Foo~1..ctor()'
```

Also if I use other ctor and call `GetEnumerator()` method:

```
let foo = FooBarSoftware.Foo<int>(1)
let e = foo.GetEnumerator() // <==

// System.MethodMissingException:
// Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0>
// FooBarSoftware.Foo`1.GetEnumerator()'.
```

Is this an compiler bug, that allows to compile interface without implementation after getting an `FS0314` warning?

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 build 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Have you tried reporting it to fsbugs@microsoft.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me.  The following runs fine.

Signature file `Foo.fsi`:

```
namespace FooBarSoftware
open System.Collections.Generic

//[<Struct>]
type Foo<'T> =
     new: unit -> 'T Foo
     new: 'T   -> 'T Foo

     // doesn't exists in implementation!
     //member public GetEnumerator: unit -> IEnumerator<'T>

     interface IEnumerable<'T>
```

Implementation file `Foo.fs`:

```
namespace FooBarSoftware
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic

//[<Struct>]
type Foo<'T> =
    val offset: int
    new () = { offset = 1 }
    new (x:'T) = { offset = 1 }

    //member this.GetEnumerator() = null :> IEnumerator<'T>

    interface IEnumerable<'T> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = null :> IEnumerator<'T>
        member this.GetEnumerator() = null :> IEnumerator
```

Test file `test.fs`:

```
module test

let foo = FooBarSoftware.Foo<int>() 
let bar = FooBarSoftware.Foo<int>(1)
let e = foo :> seq<_>
```

.

Reflector also shows `.ctor()` missing from your code.

[image: Missing Default COnstructor]

Answer (score 2):

You really don't have GetEnumerator in your class. You should read more about interfaces and inheritance in F#:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233207.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx

If you remove the GetEnumerator line from the .fsi file, this should work:

```
let foo = FooBarSoftware.Foo<int>(1)
let e = (foo :> IEnumerable<_>).GetEnumerator()
```